# MongoDB update collection after a while

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have the following collection:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5b0422b086698f39b436aa42"), "_uid" : "bQVAKHg7WWgnANHFiZOleo2FUsi4", "role" : "USER", "documentType" : "CC", "documentNumber" : 123148544, "displayName" : "Carlos Perry", "email" : "CPerry@todo.com", "phoneNumber" : "+573003004545", "photoURL" : "url", "idNetwork" : "idNetwork", "blocked" : false, "blockReason" : "Malware detection", "isDisabled": false, "lastLogin" : 1526313028249 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5b0423494bd76b3a308c5115"), "_uid" : "bQVAKHg7WWgnANHFiZOleo2FUsi3", "role" : "USER", "documentType" : "CC", "documentNumber" : 534567878, "displayName" : "Julian Cruz", "email" : "Jcruz@algo.com", "phoneNumber" : "+573003004545", "photoURL" : "url", "idNetwork" : "idNetwork", "blocked" : false, "blockReason" : "Malware detection", "isDisabled" :false, "lastLogin" : 1526313028249 }
```

And i want to update the field `"lastLogin"` five minutes after the user is logged into the application, but don't found a way to update mongo after five minutes.

I'm using **Mongoose 5.0.3** on **Node JS 9.4.0** and **Mongo 3.6.2**

Comment: You can use `setTimeout` function

Comment: Into the server or is possible to add into MongoDB ?

Comment: you cannot write it in mongodb... Do it in server file in post request...